Open 2 mate-terminal instances and run commands
I am trying to set up a script that runs 2 mate-terminal instances, each with a different command.
The script is set up as a cronjob.
The problem is, while the script works fine when executed manually, in terminal, it fails to open the 2 terminal windows.
I tried different approaches, but nothing worked. I also have gnome-terminal installed, same result.
The script runs, kills the processes and their terminal but that's it.
LE: The script runs, it kills all the processes and terminal windows but it does not open the new terminal windows with the given commands.
This is an old application and the only logging is visible in the terminal, in real time. Since there is no plan for upgrading the application anytime soon, to export the log to an external file, this is the requirement.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:10.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/lxadmin/.Xauthority
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

echo "Script started at $(date)" >> /home/lxadmin/Logs/MyApp.log

close_running_terminals() {
    echo "Closing running terminals" >> /home/lxadmin/Logs/MyApp.log
    
    pkill -f "node"
    pkill -f "npm"

    for terminal in $(pgrep -f mate-terminal); do
        if ps -o args= -p $terminal | grep -qE 'node|npm'; then
            echo "Killing mate-terminal process: $terminal" >> /home/lxadmin/Logs/MyApp.log
            kill -9 $terminal
        fi
    done

    sleep 2
}

open_terminal_and_run() {
    local cmd=$1
    echo "Running command: $cmd" >> /home/lxadmin/Logs/MyApp.log
    /usr/bin/mate-terminal -- /bin/sh -c "$cmd; exec bash"
    #/usr/bin/mate-terminal -- bash -c "$cmd; exec bash"
}

close_running_terminals

open_terminal_and_run "cd /home/lxadmin/Servers/MyApp/server && /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.13.1-linux-x64/bin/nodemon app.js"

sleep 5

open_terminal_and_run "cd /home/lxadmin/Servers/MyApp/client && /usr/local/bin/npm run dev"

echo "Script completed at $(date)" >> /home/lxadmin/Logs/MyApp.log


How does "it fails" manifest itself?

This question is similar to: A basic Bash script (to start a GUI program) works partially in cron. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@tink I can see it terminates the node / npm processes as well as closing the terminal windows but does not open new terminal windows with the given command. Basically, open_terminal_and_run does not seem to work.

@tink It seems to be the same question. However, I do have
export DISPLAY=:10.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/lxadmin/.Xauthority
as suggested in that answer.

Is there an ssh-session somewhere in the mix, or where did the :10 come from?

do you really need to run the terminal emulator to run the command?

And why the need for cron? How often is this supposed to run?

@tink Xrdp session, not SSH. I am connected to the machine via Xrdp

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk Unfortunately, yes.

@tink Once per day

@daydr3am3r: but can you explain why?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk This is an old application and the only logging is visible in the terminal, in real time. Since there is no plan for upgrading the application anytime soon, this is the requirement.

Please [edit] your question and include the information from the comments. Especially the part where you describe what the actual error is since that isn't visible from the question at all. Make sure to explain why you need a terminal for this. If the issue is logging, you can redirect output. If you explain the situation we might be able to help, but not with the lack of detail in the question.

@daydr3am3r: can you simply redirect stdout and stderr?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk I could, but it's not up to me.

@daydr3am3r: so you're not doing it on your machine? You can redirect stderr and stdout without modifying the application unless it's writing to /dev/tty or something.

@daydr3am3r - if this is an old application - what changed? And running it via RDP is a fixed requirement? Why? It would make so much more sense to run it under tmux or screen, and redirect its output to a file. Seeing output dash past in an RDP session is not exactly useful logging ...

Since Crontab does not work the way I wanted to and I thought it does, I decided to go with systemd and create a service and a timer to trigger the script at midnight.

Create the service file:
nano ~/.config/systemd/user/RestartApp.service

[Unit]
Description=Restart App via RestartApp.sh

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/RestartApp.sh


Create the timer
nano ~/.config/systemd/user/RestartApp.timer

[Unit]
Description=Restart App Daily at 00:00

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target


Enable the mechanism
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable RestartApp.timer
systemctl --user start RestartApp.timer



Not sure if this is the correct way of achieving what I wanted but it works for me.
